# How can I auto-login to a different website from my website and then get a href Link from their HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication, token

Origin of the problem: In our flying club we are sharing an account to view different approach charts on a third party website. To access them, you have to login with your credentials and then click a button that will forward to a created link. I tried using that link directly, but it contains an MD5-Hash that will be newly created at every visit and I couldn't recreate the values that are used to generate it.

My idea: Since I have the login data for the third party website and I know under which ID I can find the according href-Link, I would like the user to able to click a button on my website which causes an auto-login on the third-party side, grabs the href-Link and forwards the user to the page.

Unfortunately I can`t seem to find an appropriate way to achieve that, as the login-form also creates and uses a CSRF-Token (see example below):

```
<form name="sLogin" method="post" action="https://www.example.com/sTarget/downloads" id="login--form">
<input name="sTarget" type="hidden" value="account">
<div class="register--login-description">Einloggen mit Ihrer E-Mail-Adresse und Ihrem Passwort</div>
<div class="register--login-email">
<input name="email" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail-Adresse" type="email" autocomplete="email" tabindex="1" value="" id="email" class="register--login-field">
</div>
<div class="register--login-password">
<input name="password" placeholder="Ihr Passwort" type="password" autocomplete="current-password" tabindex="2" id="passwort" class="register--login-field">
</div>
<div class="register--login-lostpassword">
<a href="https://example.com/passwordreset" title="Passwort vergessen?">
Passwort vergessen?
</a>
</div>
<div class="register--login-action">
<button type="submit" class="register--login-btn btn is--primary is--large is--icon-right" name="Submit">Anmelden <i class="icon--arrow-right"></i></button>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="__csrf_token" value="j0LpIt1lwL4ya3UEc4C0ayDE3ZpJhd"></form>
```

Do you guys have an idea how to approach this problem? Can I somehow auto-login via PHP or JavaScript?